# Making a Cutout to in Low Poly Model without affecting the surface flow

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am making a model of Helicopter. Its comparatively low in polygons. I want to create a cutout in it. Deleting faces or doing boolean operation on major portion of model, my model becomes a mess and shape drastically changes. Can anyone suggest what is the correct way to do it.

[image: Highlighted faces I want to delete so I can create Window for Helicopter There]

[image: Shape after deleting the faces]

Adding more geometry also causes the shape to change.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is caused by the subsurface modifier.
it's the expected behavior.

You have a few options here:

— proximity loops: use `ctrl + r` to create supporting geometry around the edges of the hole

– edge crease: select the edges around the hole and press `shift + e` to change the crease weight (the edges become red)

Comment: Is there way to freeze the Mesh.